# Converting an IP address in number format to text without losing the dots

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was working with an Excel document with IP addresses in it. Some of them are in number format and when I load them into my database in text format, they lose all the dots and the address becomes useless.

I was looking for the right function to convert the number to text without losing the dots, but I wasn't able to find anything. What's the correct function?

For example, I have this IP in number format:

```
15.243.21.1
```

When I try to convert it to text, what I get is this:

```
15243211
```

Comment: What database? Exactly how are you "loading" them to it? How are you trying to convert the IP address to text? You probably need to convert them properly to text before loading them to the database.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do, convert them to text in the excel document before uploading them. But I don't get the function right.

Comment: What is the format of the cell containing the IP value?  What are your windows regional settings for decimal and thousands separator?  What is the function you are trying to use -- please provide the actual formula.

Comment: The format of the cell containing the ip is "Number".  The setting are dots for thousands separators and comas for decimals. The function that I was trying to use is the TEXT() function but after I aplied what I think is the right text format the cell format is still Number. The formula is =TEXT(Cell;"#.##0").

Comment: This needs to be fixed while the IP address is still in IP address format.  You can't back into the groupings after the fact.  You could try wrapping them in quotes.

Comment: @urko6667 Ignore the cell format.  What is the result of the formula?  I assume the formula is in a different cell than `Cell`.  What is the result of the formula:  `=ISNUMBER(cellRef_containing_ipAddress)`  ?

Comment: @urko6667 By the way, even if the cell format is `Number`, with thousands separator being the dot, ordinarily, a value of `15.243.21.1` would still be a text string, since those dots are not dividing the number into `thousands`.  If it were, then `15243211` would look like `15.243.222`.  I don't think even the various Indian versions have a `2-3-2-1` type of division.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for your help, the cell format was still number but the content was a text string, after aplying the function and changing the cell format I didn't loss the dots.

Comment: As I suspected, your problem of `losing the dots` has nothing to do with your IP addresses being numbers and not text.  You'll need to review my first two questions in my first comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function I used to fix it was this.     TEXT(Cell;"#.##0")
After that the Cell format could be number but the content is text, afer changing the cell format to text the content keeped their dots.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion the IP address is always a big binary number written using `0` and `1` only.

In your IP address `15.243.21.1` when converted to binary digits

- **15**: `00001111`
- **243**: `11110011`
- **21**: `00010101`
- **1**: `00000001`

So it is a 32 Bits IP Address Sysytem

So IP address in text format would be combination of all these four digits.

So it will be:

```
00001111111100110001010100000001
```

The derivation is very easy and you can write a formula in Excel to convert your IP address in binary address. The hardware understands only `0` and `1`. `0` means bit off `1` means bit is set on.

So entire computer hardware whatever it may be, the undergoing signals sent are sequences of `0`'s and `1`'s only. But what you see in the screen or printer is again converted back to readable form.

Comment: How do you apply this to get the OP from where they are to a solution?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question AT ALL. And it just states the obvious: That internally in the computer the ip-address is just a 32 bit number.

Comment: Using this answer’s logic, “In my opinion the text of a word is always a big binary number written using using `0` and `1` only.” So here is my comment in binary: 01010011 01101111 00100000 01101000 01100101 01110010 01100101 00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01101101 01111001 00100000 01100011 01101111 01101101 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 01101001 01101110 00100000 01100010 01101001 01101110 01100001 01110010 01111001 00101110.

Comment: First of all I am very sorry for giving unwanted answer. I thought that the address is to be pasted or to pass further for some hardware connection, which understand BITS Format Only. So I thought that if string of bits is to be passed then the answer will help in converting address to bits.

Comment: Dear JakeGould, Your comment in Binary was a befitting reply to my unfitting answer....Hats Off. Enjoyed.

Comment: If question can be elaborated then I may get Chance to Get Pass by JakeGould.